# How to run a sudo process using nohup?

Tags: ssh, sudo, nohup

How can I run a sudo command using nohup? I want to execute a sudo command and then terminate the ssh session but without interrupting or stopping the process.

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
sudo nohup . test.sh
```

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
nohup sudo <command> &
```

The second problem is the way of execution: `. script` will not work with `nohup`, as `.` is a shell internal command and `nohup` only takes executables. This should also be visible in `nohup.out` as error message.

I.e. use

```
nohup sudo /bin/bash script.sh &
```

(or whichever shell you run) or make the script an executable.

Comment: You changed `sudo nohup` into `nohup sudo`. May I ask why?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski The `nohup` is then owned by the user and not root, this would make e.g. aborting simpler (no sudo needed). Also depending on how `sudo` handles the environment, the standard location of `$HOME/nohup.out` might differ. Or ownership of it. `sudo nohup sleep 10` will have noup.out owned by root.

Comment: Thank you. I asked not because I didn't know the difference. I asked because the OP chose `sudo nohup` either deliberately or randomly. In any case an answer that chooses to change to `nohup sudo` should explain why one may want to change the order.

Answer (score 0):

Its not sudo command failure, but `.` failure because it is internal shell command. Those can be valid:

```
sudo nohup /bin/bash test.sh
```

or:

```
nohup sudo /bin/bash test.sh
```

The difference is the owner of nohup.out

Without nohup:

```
sudo /bin/bash test.sh & disown %1
```

or:

```
(sudo /bin/bash test.sh &)
```

Use > logfile 2>&1 if you need log in two latter cases. And depending on script nature you may not have to specify `.` or `/bin/bash` at all.